# What's the proper way to make the AppBar fixed?

Tags: admin-on-rest

How can I make the AppBar fixed to the top while letting only the content scroll vertically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to take the custom app route for that:

- get started by following the [documentation](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/CustomApp.html)
- implement your own `AppBar` component customizing the Material UI [component](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar). You can copy/paste the original code from [here](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/src/mui/layout/AppBar.js)

You will probably have to customize it with the style prop.

Comment: Thanks @Gildas, I'm curious though, isn't that a use-case common enough to be added to AOR as an option?

Comment: You're the first one asking for it ;)

Comment: Also, we'd like to reduce the options to the minimum. It's easy enough to customize it. It's just React™